# Ember-CLI SharePoint hosted app is it possible?

Tags: ember.js, sharepoint-2013, ember-cli, sharepoint-online

I know you can build SharePoint hosted apps using Angular or Ember.js but is there anyone that has build an app using the Ember-CLI and hosting it on SharePoint? How did you do it?

Comment: When you run `ember build`, you get a `dist` folder with JavaScript, CSS, HTML, etc, files that you can host with any static host. While I'm unfamiliar with SharePoint, if it supports Angular and Ember, then it supports Ember CLI since it's a tool for building Ember applications. You'll likely have to upload the contents of the `dist` folder.

Comment: Yes i know but how to automatically integrate the build command with the SharePoint app package is where my problem is.